# .net core application SignInAsync failing from different domain

Tags: .net, authentication, asp.net-core-2.2

when pasting the entry link into the browser, authentication works fine. But when redirected from a different domain, it fails (`HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` is false after calling `SignInAsync`).

The calling application has

```
            app.Use(async (context, next) =>
            {
                context.Response.Headers.Add("Referrer-Policy", "no-referrer");
                await next();
            });
```

and is indeed not sending the HTTP referrer in the header.

So what is going on?

This a .net core 2.2 application and my service configuration is:

```
            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.Lax;
            });
            services.AddMvc()
                    .AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
                    {
                        options.Conventions.ConfigureFilter(new IgnoreAntiforgeryTokenAttribute());//turns off AntiForgery checking
                    })
                    .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
        services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddCookie(options =>
            {
                options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Lax;
                options.AccessDeniedPath = "/AccessDenied";
            });
```

And the authentication:

```
            var claims = new List<Claim>
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, NameString)
            };

            var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(
                claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

            AuthenticationProperties properties = new AuthenticationProperties
            {
                IsPersistent = false
            };

            await HttpContext.SignInAsync(
                CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity),
                properties);
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was as simple as to use SameSiteMode.None on both theCookiePolicyOptions and the AddCookie call.